# how to create php image using session variables

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a php file called `bargraph.php` which is creating a bar chart image. I am importing `bargraph.php` in a seprate file `graph.php` using:

```
<img src='bargraph1.php'>
```

But I need to create bar chart using session variables. I need to pass variable year's value to generate image in bargraph.php. but it is not displaying the graph. I even tried with ajax. It is not happening .

graph.php

```
<script>
    alert(<?php echo $year ?>);
    var ids = $year;

    if (ids == "") { 
        document.getElementById("graph").innerHTML="";
        return;
    } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    var data = "year=" + ids ;
    //var year ="year=" +id1;
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "bargraph1.php", true); 
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");                  
    xmlhttp.send(data);

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("graph").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
</script>
```

and

`bargraph1.php`

I am using following code :

```
$year   = $_POST['year'];
$sql    = "SELECT dt,dist,cal FROM   demo where YEAR(dt)='$year'"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
```

Comment: Why not provide the year through GET, i.e. `bargraph1.php?year=2012`. Much easier and more intuitive (every year has a distinct URL).

Comment: i tried using this but still my year value is not getting fetched in bargraph1.php..plz suggest some other method if possible...

Answer (score 0):

As default response from AJAX request is plain text, i'm not sure you can display an image with : `document.getElementById("graph").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;`

I suggest another solution writing the image on disk and retrieve image from JS :
In your `bargraph1.php`

```
$img = /* Image creation*/
$filename = "images/generatedFilename.png";
imagepng($img, $filename);
echo $filename;
```

You can test your PHP code independently to be sure it works before try using it from JS.

In your ajax request

```
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = xmlhttp.responseText;
           document.getElementById("graph").appendChild(img);
        }
```

EDIT : 
The part to retrieve year isn't valid in JS.

```
alert(<?php echo $year ?>);
var ids = <?php echo $year; ?>;
```

Comment: My image is getting displayed but what i want is to create the bar chart image with the help of year value which is provided by the user. This year value needs to be passed to "bargraph.php" so that chart is generated for that particular year. but i am not able to pass the year value from "graph.php" to "bargraph.php" either through ajax or session. please helpp

Comment: My bad, bad understanding of the problem. To give the year from graph.php to bargraph.php @dtech suggest a easy solution `<img src='bargraph1.php?year=$year'> `

Comment: i tried using this but still my year value is not getting fetched in bargraph1.php..plz suggest some other method if possible...

Comment: i tried using this but still my year value is not getting fetched in bargraph1.php..plz suggest some other method if possible...

Comment: @shivani : Your ajax request in graph.php seems to be working (edit my answer to add a mistake). You should try to make this request works debugging it, or adding error messages. `if(xmlhttp.readyState!=4 || xmlhttp.status!=200)
        {
         alert (xmlhttp.readyState + " " + xmlhttp.status)
        }`

Comment: No problem @shivani :-) Don't forget to set this post resolved for others people.